# Glossary Customizing Woes

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, indentation, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I'm trying to customize a glossary style from the `glossaries`/`glossaries-extra` packages called `altlisthypergroup`.

Below is what it looks like and I have annotated the changes I'd like to make:

[image: Annotated Image]

So I would like the navigation pane centered in the page, enlarge the group headings (A, B, C,... etc), and indent the entries a bit, with the description tabbed a bit from the name of the entry.

I have read the user manuals and code manuals for both packages, as well as looked around and so far I have come up with the following code for my custom glossary style:

```
\newglossarystyle{mygls}
{
\setglossarystyle{altlisthypergroup}
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{
    \begin{description}[style=standard, labelindent=0pt]}{\end{description}}

    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\item[]\makebox[0pt]{\begin{Large}\textbf{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\end{Large}}}
}
```

and this is the result:

[image]

However, the navigation pane dissappears. Changing `labelindent` (example 28pt) moves the group heading and the entry name but not the entry description.

[image]

From what I've read, I might have to use `\glsnavigation` to bring back the navigation pane, but no sure how to do it in combination with:

```
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%  
\item[\glsnavhypertarget{##1}{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}]}
```

from the manual.

How can I edit the group heading, and entry name and description separately? Do I use `\renewenvironment{theglossary}` to bring back the navigation pane? If so, how?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[explicit, noindentafter]{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\doublespacing

%Hyperlinks Settings
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    citecolor = orange,
    linktoc=all
}

%Appendices - Acronyms, Definitions, Code
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[nopostdot,acronym,automake=immediate]{glossaries}
\usepackage[stylemods=all]{glossaries-extra}
\preto\chapter{\glsresetall} %reset acronym expansion for every chapter
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\setglossarysection{subsubsection}
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}

\newglossarystyle{mygls}
{
\setglossarystyle{altlisthypergroup}
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}
    {\begin{description}[style=standard, labelindent=0pt]}{\end{description}}
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\item[]\makebox[0pt]{\begin{Large}\textbf{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\end{Large}}}
}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ai}{AI}{Artificial Intelligence}

\newacronym{asl}{ASL}{American Sign Language}

\newacronym{rps}{RPS}{Rock Paper Scissors}

\newacronym{vr}{VR}{Virtual Reality}

%Quick Filler Text
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

%%%Document Begin%%%
\begin{document}

%Chapter Title Format
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\centering}{\huge Chapter \thechapter}{1em}{\huge #1}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-32pt}{1cm}
\chapter{Custom Glossary Woes}

\blindtext[2]
\gls{ai}
\blindtext[42]
\gls{asl}
\blindtext[12]
\gls{asl}
\kant
\gls{rps}
\kant
\gls{vr}
\kant

\newpage
\appendix
%Appendix Title Format
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\centering}{\huge Appendix \thechapter}{1em}{\huge #1}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-32pt}{1cm}
\chapter{Acronyms}
\setglossarystyle{mygls}
\printglossary[type=acronym]

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Ok I found through reading the ```enumitem``` package documentation that ```itemindent``` controls the horizontal alignment of the description of the glosaary entry. So I have made the following changes to the ```description``` block: ```labelindent=36pt```, ```itemindent=6pt``` and, inside the ```makebox``` square brackets, ```-60pt```. So I have the alignment I want, just need to bring back a centered navigation pane.

Comment: I was able to get the navigation pane back, there is actually a workable example in the documentation, glossaries-user.pdf, page 227, under the ```\glsnavigation``` but now the numbers  I used do not affect the same items. If I center the navigation pane, the group letters also centered and ```labelindent ``` does nothing and ```itemindent``` moves the navigation pane, the group letter and item label together. The item level seems to be the issue but I don't understand why ```\glsnavigation``` is inside the ```\item``` brackets in the example. Still working/hoping for a solution.

Comment: Ok so I am figuring I have to modify the ```\glossentry``` separately. There is an example in the manual, glossaries-user.pdf, page 228, under the ```\glossentry``` but it has the entry label and description on the same line. I just need to modify it so it looks like the description type entry of the original ```altlisthypergroup``` and I'll be good. Not sure how to do that yet.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I got it. Here is my code for the custom glossary definition:

```
\usepackage{needspace}
\newglossarystyle{mygls}
{
    \setglossarystyle{altlisthypergroup}
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}
    {
        \label{\thechapter}
        \begin{description}
        [style=standard, labelindent=0pt, itemindent=0pt]
    }
    {\end{description}}

    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]
    {
    \begin{center}
    \vspace{25pt}
    \glsnavhypertarget{##1}{}
    \vspace{25pt}
    \end{center}
    \needspace{6\baselineskip}\item[]\makebox[-85pt]{\begin{Large}\textbf{\glsgetgrouptitle{\hyperref[\thechapter]{##1}}}\end{Large}}
    }
    
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]
{
    \leftskip2em
    \needspace{3\baselineskip}%%%
    \item[\hspace{5pt}\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
    \ \\ \nobreak\glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2
}

\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\ifglsnogroupskip\else\vspace{0pt}\fi}
}
```

Not the most elegant, but it does what I asked.

I got the code from the glossaries-code.pdf, Section 3.3, by reading the code for `list` and `altlist` and all their variants. I modified it quite a bit.

Here is a pic of the result:

[image]

Hope it helps someone in the future.