# Making each page number link back to beginning of chapter or section

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, fancyhdr

I was wondering if it is possible to have the page numbers that appear in the footer of each page link back to the beginning of the section or chapter in which they appear.

I have this code that works for linking back to the table of contents:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% % <-- this is new
  \fancyhf{} 
  \fancyfoot[CO]{\hyperref[sec:toc]{\thepage}}
```

...that I found here: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142743/how-do-you-make-a-reference-from-all-page-numbers-to-the-toc)

I've tried using `\thechapter` and the `\thesection` as the hyperlink target but it does not work, even though I accomplished something similar in another question of mine: [Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547873/glossary-customizing-woes)

Here I have every group letter of a glossary list link back to the start of the glossary using `\thechapter` as a hyperlink target:

```
...

 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]
    {
    \begin{center}
    \vspace{25pt}
    \glsnavhypertarget{##1}{}
    \vspace{25pt}
    \end{center}
    \needspace{6\baselineskip}\item[]\makebox[-85pt]{\begin{Large}\textbf{\glsgetgrouptitle{\hyperref[\thechapter]{##1}}}\end{Large}}
    }
...
```

I'm guessing it's because `\thechapter` and `\thesection` return a chapter/section number. But not sure why it works in my other question and not here. I was thinking it was a fluke but I get a reference error when trying to link the to the beginning of the chapter using page numbers (using fancyhdr) and not when linking to the start of the glossary (renewing the glossary group header command).

Is there a way to generalize the page numbers as links to the current chapter or section?

Any help is appreciated.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\emergencystretch=1em

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{} 
  \fancyfoot[CO]{\hyperref[sec:toc]{\thepage}} 
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

%Quick Filler Text
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\label{sec:toc}
\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{intro}
\blindtext[5]

\chapter{Next}
\label{next}
\blindtext[3]
\blinditemize
\blindtext[2]

\section{And Then}
\label{andthen}
\blindtext[6]
\blindenumerate

\chapter{Math}
\label{math}
\blindtext[5]

\section{Some Math}
\label{somemath}
\blindmathpaper

\chapter{Conclusion}
\label{conclusion}
\blindtext{20}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \thechapter works (probably) in your other question, because you have a \label{\thechapter} which gives a suitable anchor. But your code is not suitable for tests. Create a sensible complete and *minimal* example without all this \vspace and other formatting commands.

Comment: I was hoping the solution would be a simple "replace `sec:toc` with `\magicmacro`". In any case, I've provided a MWE.

Comment: This method seems to work: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270141/make-an-hyperref-link-to-current-chapter-section), by placing `\theHsection` near chapter\section declarations and the `\hyperlink` code inside the `\fancyhdrcode` but it takes me to the first word of the chapter/section instead of the title. Nit picky, I know :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\emergencystretch=1em

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[CO]{\rightmark}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}

%Quick Filler Text
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\chaptermark#1{\markboth
  {\MakeUppercase {\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \@chapapp \ \thechapter . \ \fi #1}}
  {\protect\hyper@linkstart{link}{\@currentHref}{to current chapter: \protect\thepage}\protect\hyper@linkend}}

\def\sectionmark#1{\markright{\protect\hyper@linkstart{link}{\@currentHref}{to current section: \protect\thepage}\protect\hyper@linkend}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\label{sec:toc}
\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{intro}
\blindtext[5]

\chapter{Next}
\label{next}
\blindtext[3]
\blinditemize
\blindtext[2]

\section{And Then}
\label{andthen}
\blindtext[6]
\blindenumerate

\chapter{Math}
\label{math}
\blindtext[5]

\section{Some Math}
\label{somemath}
\blindmathpaper

\chapter{Conclusion}
\label{conclusion}
\blindtext{20}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work better. The method I was using occasionally breaks if there are no sections or paragraphs. Is there a way to adapt this to unnamed chapters (`\chapter*`) like TOC/LOF, References,etc?

Comment: I had to use a combination of the method I posted as an answer and the solution provided by @fischer to get both named and unnamed chapters to work, although I would have rather have found a nice solution like `fischer` for both unnamed chapters and subsections (and maybe subsubsections). Thanks `fischer`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a label to the chapter title and then refer to it via \pageref

```
...
\chapter{xx}\label{ch:xx}
... further content goes here
Put something like this where you want the page reference: Chapter ``\nameref{ch:xx}'' is on \pageref{ch:xx} (you only need the pageref-command)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work if I try and put `\nameref` in the `fancyhdr` code. Get an error when about a missing '}'. It will work anywhere else, but I need them in the page numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works, had to redefine chapter and section formats:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\emergencystretch=1em

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[explicit, noindentafter]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\AtBeginDocument{\def\chapterautorefname{Chapter}}%
\AtBeginDocument{\def\sectionautorefname{Section}}%

%Chapter Title Format
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\hypertarget{section::\theHsection}{}\bfseries\centering}{\huge Chapter \thechapter}{1em}{\huge #1}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-32pt}{1cm}

%Section Title Format
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\hypertarget{section::\theHsection}{}\bfseries}{\large\thesection \hspace{6pt} #1}{3pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{16pt}{-18pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{} 
  \fancyfoot[CO]{\hyperlink{section::\theHsection}{\thepage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

%Quick Filler Text
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\label{sec:toc}
\pagestyle{plain}


\chapter{Introduction}
\label{intro}
\blindtext[5]

\chapter{Next}
\label{next}
\blindtext[3]
\blinditemize
\blindtext[2]

\section{And Then}
\label{andthen}
\blindtext[6]
\blindenumerate

\chapter{Math}
\label{math}
\blindtext[5]

\section{Some Math}
\label{somemath}
\blindmathpaper

\chapter{Conclusion}
\label{conclusion}
\blindtext{20}
\end{document}
```

It works on my MWE, will test it later on my thesis and report back.

Comment: there is no need to add more targets - hyperref already adds them. You only need the right code to use them.

Comment: But then how to refer to them in a general sense? Like I am trying to have the page numbers link to the nearest chapter/section, which is my I am using a modified `fancyhdr` definition.

Comment: my answer links to the nearest chapter/section.